# why can't i call the erase of set in c++ from the destructor?

Tags: c++, class, set

I have encountered a problem while studying Chapter 13.4 of the C++ Primer book. I defined two `class` types in C++, and one of the classes contains a set variable that stores `pointers` to another class type. Now, I have defined a `destructor` for the class type `record`. When an element of this class type `record` is destructed, the `destructor` will delete the address stored in the `file` set of the class. However, when I run this program, the system crashes. I just want to know what happened. Thank you very much.

Actually, this is a known problem in C++ Primer 13.4. I wrote a similar but more simple code to reproduce the same bug,  Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
class file;
class record {
public:
    ~record() {
        deletefun();
    }
    
    int x;
    std::set<file*> file_log;
    void deletefun();
};
class file {
public:
    std::set<record*> ptr_to_record;
    void remove(record* e) 
    { 
        std::cout << e->x << std::endl;
        ptr_to_record.erase(e); 
    }
};
void record::deletefun() {
    for (auto i : file_log) 
        i->remove(this);
}
int main() {
    record e1;
    e1.x = 10;
    file n1;
    e1.file_log.insert(&n1);
}
```

I tried to output the size of the "file" class variable, and it's 1, which means that there is an address stored in the set. However, I can't access the set at all, not even the begin element.

My OS is Windows, and I compiled this code in Visual Studio 2022.

[image]

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/TW8Y3c5se

Comment: Aha, I see the issue, `n1` is declared after `e1` so `n1` is destroyed first when main ends which means that when `e1` is destroyed the `i` in `i->remove(this);` is a dangling pointer. There is no `file` object where the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Using `std::shared_ptr<file>` instead of a raw pointer will automatically take care of objects lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

`e1` is created before `n1`.
Thus, `e1` is destroyed after `n1`.
So when you get to the destruction of `e1`, `n1` has already been destroyed, and `i->remove(this);` tries to access the destroyed object.
You need to make sure that all `file`s outlive the `record`s that store their addresses.

Comment: "You need to make sure that all `file`s outlive the `record`s that store their addresses." Is dangerous advice to a newbie; they might just change the declaration order and call it done, even though they're leaving the code brittle as glass. Better, change the design so either 1) `record`s *can't* outlive the `file` (e.g. all records store a `shared_ptr` to the common `file`) or 2) `record`s can *detect* when the `file` is gone (e.g. all records store a `weak_ptr` to the common `file`, so the `file` isn't kept alive by `record`s, but they also know when it's gone and can skip the cleanup)

Comment: I would just not have a destructor; the MRE doesn't indicate a need. `std::set` is perfectly capable of cleaning itself up, and there is no indication about ownership here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't know before that a variable created later would be destroyed earlier. After I defined a `destructor` in the `File`  which will erase its address stored in the `Record` , the problem was solved.